# How is this working? There is no W,Y,G wires?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, nest

Single stage gas furnace and ac w Honeywell thermostat w no W,Y, nor G. How would this work? I’m trying to convert to nest.

[image]

Comment: Can you get us the model information off the existing thermostat & interface module?  Also, I take it your photo is of the wiring at the thermostat?

Comment: First of all the Nest will need 24 Volt, that is your R and Rc.

Comment: then you need wires at Nest to connect the  W, G, Y, Heat, Fan, Cooling

Comment: finally you need the C, common at Nest

Comment: There's a Honeywell module down at your A/C unit, that actually has the wires you expect. You're going to need to take a close look at the thermostat cable and see how many wires it has *available*.  Any chance you can upgrade the thermostat cable to an 8-wire?